# Material difference between Mixed Effects Model and normal Linear Model

Tags: r, linear-model, lme4-nlme, mixed-model, lm

I have a question about normal linear models vs mixed models.

Say I'm predicting prices for certain products, and I know two things: store and brand:

In a linear model (lm), this would be:

```
price ~ 1 + store + brand
```

in a mixed effects model (lmer from lme4), this would be

```
price ~ 1 + (1 | store) + (1 | brand)
```

I keep on reading that mixed effects models are great because e.g. different stores have different effects (think Whole Foods vs Costco, expensive vs cheap), but I don't see how a normal linear model doesn't track that anyways. If store and brand are factors, then doesn't each unique store get transformed into its own boolean variable? (For each price i, it was or it was not gathered from store j, so if there are ten different stores, that'll be turned into ten different indicator columns in the data matrix X).

How exactly does a mixed effects model do better than this?

Comment: You might want to look for the difference between `fixed` and `random` effects.

Answer (score 1):

Random effects will have a different intercept for each group.  Thus, each store will have a different intercept vs a common intercept.  If each store is an indicator, the result is exactly the same. Imagine you had 100 stores, that means 100 indicators, not very easy to understand.

Gelman talks about this on pg 346 of his multilevel modeling book.

Comment: Is that a legal copy of Gelman & Hill? If not, it needs to be deleted from the site. You can always reference the book & link to, say, amazon.

Comment: @Gung It is (fortunately) not our responsibility to police all links. However, if such a link appears to be to a copy of questionable legality, we can expect it to become invalid soon, limiting its usefulness.

Comment: "If each store is an indicator, the result is exactly the same."
Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are writing here, but I don't think that this is correct. The OLS solution with a dummy for each store should not give the same estimates in general as a mixed effects model with a random intercept for slope. The predicted store-level random intecepts in LMM are shrunk towards the grand mean, especially for stores that have few observations. So the store-level predictions from the models should not be the same. Also, the degrees of freedom differ between the models.